# Javascript functions that adds three inputs

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to Javascript so sorry in advance if its because of dumb errors.

I need to add "salaire", "pension" and "autre" and show it in an input after I click a button. I am not sure if I used the right tags in my code probably more suitable ones.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   <head>    
    <meta charset="urf-8"/>
    <script>
  function revenue_mensuel()
    {
      var salaire = document.getelementsbyname("salaire");
  var pension = document.getelementsbyname("pension");
  var autre = document.getelementsbyname("autre");
   return {salaire+pension+autre}
   document.getElementById("revenue").value = revenue_mensuel();
   }
  </script>
   <style>

  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 vos revenus mensuels </h1>
  <br/>
   <div>
    <form>
      salaire mensuel (avant impots):
     <input type="number and decimal/floats" name="salaire">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <form>
      pension alimentaire recus:
    <input type="number and decimal/floats" name="pension">
    </form>
    <br/>
    <form>
     autre revenue mensuels:
     <input type="number and decimal/floats" name="autre">
     </form>
     <br/>
    <form>
     total des revenue mensuel:
    <input id="revenue" type="text"/>
    <input type="button" onclick='revenue_mensuel()'/>
     </form>   
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A list of technical issues

- Javascript is case-sensitive so method you want is `getElementsByName` and not `getelementsbyname`
- the `getElementsByName` return a list of elements (*so you need to specify which in the list*) in your case it is the 1st one always. so you need to access it with `[0]`
- then you need to extract the actual value of the input with `.value`.
- you need to convert the string to a number. (*adding `+` at the start, or using `parseInt` will do the trick*)

In the concept

- You are calling the `revenue_mensuel` from inside it self, causing an infinite loop.
- you do not need to return anything from the function since you assign the result to the element directly.

Html issues

- you have left the `h1` open
- you do not need a different `form` for each input element

---

All changes together give

```js
function revenue_mensuel() {
  var salaire = +document.getElementsByName("salaire")[0].value;
  var pension = +document.getElementsByName("pension")[0].value;
  var autre = +document.getElementsByName("autre")[0].value;
  document.getElementById("revenue").value = salaire + pension + autre;
}
```

```html
 <h1> vos revenus mensuels </h1>
<br/>
<div>
  <form>
    salaire mensuel (avant impots):
    <input type="number and decimal/floats" name="salaire">
    <br/>pension alimentaire recus:
    <input type="number and decimal/floats" name="pension">
    <br/>autre revenue mensuels:
    <input type="number and decimal/floats" name="autre">
    <br/>total des revenue mensuel:
    <input id="revenue" type="text" />
    <input type="button" onclick='revenue_mensuel()' />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<input type="number" name="...">
```

there is no such thing as *type="number and decimal/floats"*

This validator will help you fix your code: http://validator.w3.org/